# What does $cell: [true, false] do in CellJS?

Tags: javascript, celljs

I'm spending some time learning [CellJS](https://www.celljs.org/). According to the docs `$cell` is one of the special keywords and states:

> Required. Tells Cell to create a cell element using this object as a root

Many of the examples on CellJS use `$cell: true`. But in playing around I've changed this to `$cell: false`, and the app seems to work the same. Removing the key/value pair does cause the app to not work however.

Why does changing the `$cell` value to `false` seem to have no effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Point!

As you can see [here](https://github.com/intercellular/cell/blob/develop/cell.js#L504), currently the `$cell` attribute is used for detecting the objects to automatically turn into cells.

And it's only used as a "marker", so just by adding the `$cell` marker you have shown your intent to turn it into a cell, which means it doesn't look at what value it contains, which is why `$cell: false` also works. It really doesn't matter what value it contains as long as the `$cell` attribute is there. So even if you do something like `$cell: document.body` it would still work (although not recommended)

We *could* make it so that `$cell: false` doesn't create a cell, but I am not sure why someone would do that when you can just exclude that key. But perhaps I'm missing your use case. In that case, please feel free to open an issue on Github https://github.com/intercellular/cell/issues/new and we can continue the discussion!